# Scrolling menu on iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have problem with my dropdown menu on iPhone. Whenever I have more than 6 links on my menu the list is too long and whenever I want to scroll it little bit down with finger I can't because I press on link and its instantly fire to another url. How I can avoid that and recognize that I want to scroll menu little bit down and how to recognize if I tapped a menu li to go into another url?

```
$(".content-bar--content").on("click", function() {
           window.location.href = link;
       });
```

This is what my code looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://www.falise.com/blog/prevent-click-event-scrolling-ipad/ without jquery

First we check if the device is iOS or not

```
var iOS = agent.indexOf('iphone') >= 0 || agent.indexOf('ipad') >= 0;
```

We also need a variable which will tell us if the screen is being touched and moved.

```
var touchMoving = false;
```

Then for iOS only add event listeners that listen for `touchmove` and `touchend` that will set `touchMoving` to the appropriate value.

```
if (iOS)
{  
  document.addEventListener("touchmove", function(e)
  {
     touchMoving = true;
  });

  document.addEventListener("touchend", function(e)
  {
    touchMoving = false;
  });
}
```

Now when a link with a class `content-bar--content` is clicked while scrolling it will prevent the click event because touchMoving is true.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.content-bar--content').forEach(elem => {
    elem.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        if (touchMoving) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});
```